# Copyright content removal and privacy policy

Tags: asp.net, html, web-crawler, privacy

In most of the musical site i found that, they use to write below thing in Policies:

On this website(www.Indiamp3.com) you find links that lead to audio files. These files are stored somewhere else on the internet and are NOT a part of this website. Indiamp3.com does NOT carry ANY responsibility for them, Indiamp3.com ONLY COLLECTS links and INDEXES other sites contents. Our website is fully automatized. This means that we are crawling other mp3 websites and directories, indexing them and then linking to those mp3 files they offer. **Indiamp3.com respects the american DMCA laws.**

If your copyrighted material has been indexed by Indiamp3.com and you want this material removed, you must provide a written communication with exact reference to the content you claim ownership to. This message must contain following:

- Name and the exact URL of your copyrighted material.
- Contact information so that we may contact you (street address, phone and email).
- Clear proof of evidence that you own the copyright to said content or evidence that you are a representative of the person/company owning the content.

---

How to do such indexing, if I have link of an file on other website?

Comment: after searching on internet..i did not find any information on this. So please provide me link on web..that can help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are probably looking for this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

Comment: thx JVA for response..If you see my que..It say : One file (for ex .mp3) stored on other server, can be indexed in such a way that you can show the link of that file in your web..but it will show like it is stored in your server.                                                                 In simple words, I can use mp3 file stored in  other server, by indexing..and it seems to the user it is stored in my server. But actually it is coming from different server.

Comment: actually i copied my question , form one of the musical site...When i dig, i found lots of site, are doing this.   ..........So i just want to know , how we can do this...If you want check....check here ....http://indiamp3.com/music/terms.htm